# Python twisted: A server that writes to the connection after an asynchronous operation?

Tags: python, networking, asynchronous, twisted, deferred

I have a server where I have implemented a child of the NetstringReceiver protocol. I want it to perform an asynchronous operation (using txredisapi) based on the client's request and then respond with the results of the operation. A generalization of my code:

```
class MyProtocol(NetstringReceiver):
  def stringReceived(self, request):
    d = async_function_that_returns_deferred(request)
    d.addCallback(self.respond)
    # self.sendString(myString)

  def respond(self, result_of_async_function):
    self.sendString(result_of_async_function)
```

In the above code, the client connecting to my server does not get a response. However, it does get myString if I uncomment

```
# self.sendString(myString)
```

I also know that result_of_async_function is a non-empty string because I print it to stdout .

What can I do that will allow me to respond to the client with the result of the asynchronous function?

Update: Runnable source code

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, protocol
from twisted.protocols.basic import NetstringReceiver
from twisted.internet.task import deferLater

def f():
  return "RESPONSE"

class MyProtocol(NetstringReceiver):
  def stringReceived(self, _):
    d = deferLater(reactor, 5, f)
    d.addCallback(self.reply)
    # self.sendString(str(f())) # Note that this DOES send the string.

  def reply(self, response):
    self.sendString(str(response)) # Why does this not send the string and how to fix?

class MyFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
  protocol = MyProtocol

def main():
  factory = MyFactory()
  from twisted.internet import reactor
  port = reactor.listenTCP(8888, factory, )
  print 'Serving on %s' % port.getHost()
  reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have `reactor.callLater(X, d.callback, ...)` somewhere?

Comment: The above code is only what I believe to be the relevant part. I have a factory using this protocol and I call reactor.listenTCP(port, factory, ).

Comment: Can you please fill out this example more thoroughly?  Make it complete, and runnable?  You've got the right idea here, which means that the problem is in the specifics, so in order to answer your question I need to see the specifics.  You can simulate asynchronous operations for demonstration purposes with `twisted.internet.task.deferLater`.

Comment: @Glyph, thanks for your input. I've written runnable code that illustrates the problem. Just in case I might be doing something wrong in the way I run it: 1. I run the file: python example.py 2. In another shell: nc localhost 8888 1:a, In this case I do get back a response from the commented out sendString but not from the sendString inside reply(self, response)

P.S: Sorry for the late response, I'd replied earlier but just discovered the [at]username feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one specific feature about `NetstringReceiver`:

> The connection is lost if an illegal message is received

Are you sure that your messages conform  [djb's Netstring protocol](http://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt)?

Obviously the client sends illegal string that could not be parsed, and connection is lost by protocol conditions. *Everything else looks good in your code*.

If you don't need that specific protcol, you'd better inherit [`LineReceiver`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html) instead of `NetstringReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might re-write using the LineReceiver protocol if all else fails but I'm not quite ready to give up on NetstringReceiver. I'm fairly certain that my problem isn't related to mis-formatting (I believe that NetstringReceiver takes care of the formatting for me). Like I said the commented out sendString does actually work, so I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the way I'm using the deferred. I actually suspect the connection is closing before the deferred fires..

Comment: You're correct that if you're using sendString (and never transport.write) that `NetstringReceiver` should handle the syntax of the netstrings themselves for you.

Comment: So I finally decided to switch to LineReceiver and it worked. I'm still not sure why NetstringReceiver didn't work because I am fairly certain I used it correctly. Maybe its a bug? NOTE: You should use telnet instead of netcat if you are using lineReceiver (because of delimiter issues)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you never get the response is because by the time it's sent the connection is closed. The reason the connection is closed is because the message you send with 'nc' is:

`1:a,\n`
Because you have to type a newline to get nc to send the message, but nc includes it as part of the message. That violates the NetString protocol...
I worked around it (with your code modified with some additional prints) by sending this message instead:

`1:a,40:\n
blahblahblah`**Don't hit return here, just wait for the reply**

`8:RESPONSE,`